# How do I install custom fonts in shinyapps.io apps?

Tags: r, github, shiny, fonts, shinyapps

This question relates to an answer given by Yihui here:

https://groups.google.com/g/shinyapps-users/c/0czcsM4vziM/m/GNuyL3ClCgAJ

In the instruction, it says to:

1. dir.create('~/.fonts')
2. Download the fonts, e.g. via download.file(), to ~/.fonts
3. Run system('fc-cache -f ~/.fonts')

I've put this into my .app code (just after all my library() calls) before trying to deploy the app to shinapps.io.:

```
dir.create('~/.fonts') 
download.file('https://github.com/**MY USERNAME**/fonts', '~/.fonts')
system('fc-cache -f ~/.fonts')
```

As you can see, I have put all the fonts the app requires into a public repo on my github account. This is the URL that the font .ttf files are from. However, i think i may have misunderstood the directions, as i get this error from shinyapps.io:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Error sourcing /srv/connect/apps/font/app.R
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

The fonts I wish to use are derivations of the "Sarabun" and "Garamond" families.

Please can someone provide more detail to Yihui's solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you also have another solution that would be good to hear. However, please note that 'font style packages' tend not to work with shinyapps.io as these look locally for the styles, which defeats the purpose of it! Additionally, I wish to use a specific .ttf file.

Cheers all,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL `https://github.com/**MY USERNAME**/fonts` points to a repository overview, not the folder itself, so maybe you are downloading just the HTML page on that URL.

You need to download the archive depending on your OS (ZIP on Windows, .TAR.GZ on Unix-alike).

```
download.file("https://github.com/**USERNAME**/fonts/archive/master.tar.gz", destfile = "fonts.tar.gz")

# or ZIP file on Windows
download.file("https://github.com/**USERNAME**/fonts/archive/master.zip", destfile = "fonts.zip")
```

Then you have to extract the archive:

```
untar("fonts.tar.gz", exdir = "~/.fonts/")

# or with ZIP file on Windows
unzip("fonts.zip", exdir = "~/.fonts/")
```

Then you can use that in your script:

```
system('fc-cache -f ~/.fonts')
```

I hope the way is clear as it may vary depending on your OS, fonts and subfolders etc... Something like that should work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for pointing this out to me! This answer has given rise to another issue, as normal! At the moment, with your solution i have: dir.create('~/.fonts') download.file("github.com**USERNAME**/fonts/archive/master/fonts.zip", destfile = "fonts.zip") unzip("fonts.zip", exdir = "~/.fonts") system('fc-cache -f ~/.fonts') However, my formulas (within my package) have calls such as: extrafont::ttf_import(system.file("extdata/fonts", package = "*******")) What is the best way to amend these to look at the .fonts path we have created on shinapps.io?

Comment: @Dussek I think it could be enough to call `extrafont::ttf_import("~/.fonts/")`, but it again depends on your directory structure and your R code. If this will not work, feel free to open a new question with details...

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Ive included this into my code and have posted the new issue here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771749/use-a-custom-font-within-shinyapps-io